# What is the fastest way to get the position of highest (most left) bit in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Let's say, we receive a binary representation of a number - how we can get the highest bit set in it (e.g. the biggest power of 2)?

For example: integer `9` -> binary `00001001` -> most left bit position `3`

Comment: What do you expect for 0, for -1?

Comment: what kind of numbers are you dealing with: 32 bit? 64 bit? arbitrary (BigInt)?

Comment: let's put it simple: 32bit, only non-negative integers, for edge-case of zero let's return null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the less-known native function [`Math.clz32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32):

```js
const msb = n => 31 - Math.clz32(n);
console.log(msb(0b1001)); // 3
```

Comment: amazing, learned something new today.

Comment: I was originally thinking about leveraging Math.log2() somehow, but this one is definitely better and straight-forward